# kotlin getparameters function not working

Tags: kotlin, compiler-errors, kotlinx.coroutines

I get constantly:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource not found in classpath: kotlin/coroutines/coroutines.kotlin_builtins`

while I try to get parameters of any object as pointet in example below:

`::flagDbInfo.parameters`

I've added following dependencies to my maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.30.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using version 1.3.0 I would recommend the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I have the same issue, having both the dependencies in `pom.xml` (actually, I have version 1.3.10 but the rest is the same), but it does not help. I am not even aware where I use the `coroutines`, all I know is that when I use version 1.2.70 all works, but after upgrading to 1.3.10 I get the same error as in the OP. Well, the only difference with your solution is that I use `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8`.

Comment: I had the same issue. somehow `kotlin-stdlib` was pulled with version 1.2.70 (it is a transitive dependency of `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8`), even if my `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` was 1.3.10 (and `kotlin-stdlib` was not declared in the pom.xml). The solution was to force (ie add as yet another dependency) in the pom.xml to also have `kotlin-stdlib` with the same version as `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8`

Answer (score 4):

Got the same error, working on a Spring Boot app, with IntelliJ 2019.1, kotlin 1.3.30.
The following configuration (in pom.xml) fixed it:

```
<dependencies>
... (your other dependencies)
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.30</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
<plugins>
...
<plugin>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <version>1.3.30</version>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                </args>
                <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <source>src/main/java</source>
                            <source>src/main/kotlin</source>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals> <goal>test-compile</goal> </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
...
</plugins>
```

Also, I originally had the kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 artifact as a dependency as well, but if the kotlin-stdlib artifact is included, the jdk8 one is not needed. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#kotlin-standard-library-artifacts-and-split-packages for more details.